# Updating data from the DataGridView into the database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

This is how I populate my DataGridView in the form load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.animalsTableAdapter.Fill(this.animalsDataSet.Animals);
}
```

After changes are made in the DataGridView, I would like to update the bounded database when a "Save" button is clicked, so I have tried this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.animalsTableAdapter.Update(this.animalsDataSet.Animals);
}
```

It doesn't give any error message, but it doesn't work either, meaning the changes in the DataGridView are not reflected into the bounded database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 - C# - dataGridView save changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796908/visual-studio-2010-c-datagridview-save-changes)

Comment: This question is asked about twice a week here, why don't you go through all the suggestions in the answers first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recall binding method for gridview.
    Write this line just below the Update method.

```
 this.animalsTableAdapter.Fill(this.animalsDataSet.Animals);
```