# Updating Datagridview values into database

Tags: c#

I am developing an forms application where user can get tables data from database 
 into    gridviewcontrol which is editable so that user can update some data in the grid and when user clicks update buttonon the form the updated datagrid values should update in database. User can update more column values at a time.
I am working on datagrids for the frist time and I managed to get data from databse and display in data grid but I am not able to update edited data back top database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the links below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12846/Auto-Saving-DataGridView-Rows-to-a-SQL-Server-Data

[C# Issue: How do I save changes made in a DataGridView back to the DataTable used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520051/c-sharp-issue-how-do-i-save-changes-made-in-a-datagridview-back-to-the-datatabl)

[WinForms DataGridView - update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623548/winforms-datagridview-update-database)

[C# WinForms - how to send updates from DataGridView to DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051390/c-sharp-winforms-how-to-send-updates-from-datagridview-to-database)

[Save changes in dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796908/visual-studio-2010-c-sharp-datagridview-save-changes)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a DataTable as a source to the DataGrid that shouldn't be so hard , you can get the changes in the DataTable using datatable.getchanges() // search for an example in getchanges()

and then update each row that has changed using the unique key ( i assume you have one ) of the row .

If you need to know how you update back to the database then you should check msdn for the exact method you have to use , depending of course on  the one you used to load the data to the grid .